# SQL Server : statistic of each database, How much each db is used

Tags: sql-server

I want statistic of each database in a SQL Server instance.

For each database, I want to know how many triggers, stored procedures, etc.

Maybe also link between databases.

Any stat useful for migration, usage report, statistical development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Catalog Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) in SQL Server - they tell you pretty much everything.

Number of triggers?

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.triggers
```

Number of stored procedures?

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.procedures
```

and so on - the possibilities are endless.....

Comment: is there a way to do something like FROM sys.* . And could we do the query for each database in 1 shot.

Comment: @forX: you could have a look at the `sys.objects` which contains all the objects, and pick those you want. But no, this is on a **per-database** level - you cannot do it across all databases.

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you need

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC sp_spaceused'
```

This link gives you [more details](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx)

There are a few other undocumented stored procedures, one for tables for example, that are useful.

Comment: EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; SELECT * FROM sys.objects order by type_desc'

Comment: tanks for your answer, it resolve a part of my question. Can only accept 1 answer

Comment: No worries. As long as you got a solution. Enjoy.